# Explanation on the proof of the strong maximum principle for the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In the Evans PDE book, we have the following

[image]

The proof is below. I would like an explanation of the underlined part, with more details.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a topological property of $\mathbb{R}^n$: if $O\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty, connected and open, then $O$ is path-connected. Moreover, given $x,y\in O$, there exists a path joining $x$ and $y$ formed by segments parallel to the coordinate axis.

**Proof**

The result is clearly true if $O$ is a ball or a cube.

Fix $x_0\in O$ and let $U=\{x\in O:x_0\text{ can be joined to }x\text{ by such a path}\}$.

1. $U\neq\emptyset$ ($x_0\in U$)
2. $U$ is open (if $x\in U$, then there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset U$...)
3. $U$ is closed in $O$ (if $x\in O\setminus U$, then there exists $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset O\setminus U$...)

Since $O$ is cnncted, this implies $U=O$.